# MATLAB read 3gp audio files so I can do an FFT

Tags: matlab, audio

In my MATLAB scripts I've been doing something similar to the following to read .wav files;

```
[ref_data1,fs1,nbits1] = wavread('sample1.wav');
```

And from there I've been able to use ref_data1 nicely with other functions such as `fft()`.

How can I do this if I have `sample1` as a 3gp file?

Thanks.

Comment: can you convert it (outside Matlab) to `wav`?

Comment: Here's the thing. I'm using MATLAB purely for prototyping. This is actually for an Android application. And I'm recording the user's voice as a .3gp file within the app, and unsure if I can convert right there to a .wav.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From [Matlab Documentation](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/import_export/supported-file-formats.html), if you have Matlab on a Mac you can use [`VideoReader`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/videoreaderclass.html) it supports file Formats supported by QuickTime, including .3gp.

Otherwise, I'd convert to `.wav` outside matlab.